# Seeting Active Nav for Bootstrap in WordPress

Tags: theme-development, navigation

OK , I have a Custom Theme generated by Bootstrap. Currently I just added a Navbar (navigation to the theme and I am having trouble on setting ACTIVE navbar in each active page.(by adding `active` class to the li)
For example if I am in Contact us page how I can force the navbar to make the contact us nav active!
I alreadt tried

```
<li <?php is_page( 'Home' ){echo 'class="active"'}> Home</li>
<li <?php is_page( 'About us' ){echo 'class="active"'}> About us</li>
```

can you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make clear and understandable what you're asking, additionally read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its just your PHP formatting, you have the right idea! try this:

```
<pre class="prettyprint"><code class="language-php">
<?php 

if (is_page( 'Home' ) {
    $class="active";
}
elseif (is_page( 'About' ) {
    $class="active";
}
else {
    $class="";
}

?>

<li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"Home</li>
<li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"About</li>
</code></pre>
```

Comment: Can you please add more explanation to your answer?

Comment: Hi Frank I like your idea and look logical to me but it is not working! I mean there must be syntax error since I am getting white blank page from WordPress!

Comment: Does anyone have any Idea about this? Please?